# Access Queries like command Wildcard

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I want to use the like command in a query to find specific results in Access. In the field that I want to utilize the like command has the wildcard (*) command in that field, which I want to search by. Is there a way around this? Example below:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '*'
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?  I for one have no idea what you want you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to find columns that actually contain an asterisk (*) via the LIKE operator, here is an idea to try (see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/using-wildcard-characters-in-string-comparisons-HP001032284.aspx )

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '[*]'
```

The square brackets indicate that it's a literal asterisk to match, and not a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is not a wildcard in sql server `like`. So you can use:

```
SELECT *     
FROM TABLE_NAME     
WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '%*%' ;
```

If you want to search for actual wildcard `%`, you can change the wilcard to something else say `&`

```
SELECT *     
FROM TABLE_NAME     
WHERE FIELD_NAME LIKE '&%&' ESCAPE '&';
```